# Arabic font does not render properly

Tags: ffmpeg, video, fonts, arabic

I have a font called 'me_quran' that looks like this:

[me_quran font on wordpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0fRw.png)

Unfortunately, when FFMPEG renders it, the vowels (the little lines you see) are either too high or too low on the letters.

[ffmpeg rendering the me_quran font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5J1X.png)

I think this is due to the way FFMPEG renders the font, but is it possible to correct this to have the same font as seen in wordpad?

ps: the text on the video is rendered in a `.ass` subtitle file.

Thank you

Used command:

```
-y -i "{inputVideoPath}" -filter_complex "subtitles='{subtitleFilePath}'" -c:a copy "{outputVideoPath}"
```

The font is specified in the .ass subtitle file.

Comment: Hello, ffmpeg is a CLI tool. When asking for help about CLI tool, you should include the used command at the very minimum.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: were you able to find a valid font? @RayaneStaszewski, if so can you please drop a link? facing similar issue. thanks

Comment: hi @RustyPythonicScript, I did find a solution! I'll post it under this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure the proper functioning of any Arabic font, it is necessary to utilize FFMPEG with 'harfbuzz' as an add-on.

1. Download the ffmpeg package from the following link: https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/. Look for the file named `ffmpeg-git-full.7z`.
2. Extract the contents of the downloaded archive.
3. Place the extracted files in your PATH or replace the existing ffmpeg executable with the new one.

The new executable already includes 'harfbuzz'.

Now, you can use ffmpeg for Arabic fonts as you did previously, but with the updated executable and it should render properly!

I hope it helps